# Insert one-to-one relationship on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-one

I'm trying to add the comment on an article and insert it into database. There is not error but the data is not inserted

Here is Article model

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :comment, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

And It's the Comment model

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :comment, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

But I still not sure about the controller how it should be. Please help, thank you

Comment: `id` in `{id:id}` is a DOM node. Is this missing a `.value`?

Comment: how it should be?

Comment: This totally depends on what the element with id `kpm` is, and what value of this element you actually want.

Comment: I did it but there is another error

Comment: Please, don't change question to something completely different. Just ask another one

Comment: And add Comment model code (you've duplicated Article) and controller code